# Change color of hands inside a TimePicker watch. Material design?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget, android-theme, timepicker

I made my own style in styles.xml and it looks like this:

```
<style name="myTimePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#88000000</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

My question si how can I change the color of the clock hands (for hour and time) to be the same color as the header?

[image: This is how it looks. the clock hands should be the same color as the background]

Comment: do you want to change color of Clock's Hours ? I mean 1, 2, 3, ...11, 12 ?

Comment: No. I want to change the clock's hands. as in the bluish green thing that points to the chosen hour. (arrow with circle on top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via XML, for API Level 21 or higher:

```
android:numbersSelectorColor="@color/Blue"
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try this but may be it could help you.
Just add these two attributes in your style

```
<style name="myTimePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#88000000</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/background</item>

    <!-- clock hand color change -->

     <item name="android:hand_hour">#88000000</item>
    <item name="android:hand_minute">#88000000</item>
</style>
```

You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32550150/2022000), May be it could help you.

**EDIT**

I searched on web for long, and got this solution.
These two properties may work for you.

```
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#ff2d6073</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#ffdddddd</item>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700548/2022000)

Comment: I tried both what you suggest. While setting a color from R.colors or even a drawable on the hand_hour and hand_minute. but does nothing :(
And from that post, I already tried it and none of those attr are for the hands

Comment: @rosualin I've update my answer, try that it has source also. may be it could help you.

Comment: I tried it like that but it doesn't work. :| I commented on the source stack overflow question, maybe he will have time to let me know

Answer (score 2):

You need to set colorControlNormal and colorControlActivated in your TimePicker style as follows:

```
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
```